# PHP Date DIff - mandate return of 2 characters

Tags: php

I am attempting to update a field via sql that has 12(qty) 0's. The 0's are coupled together for a total of 6 pair to represent Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, ex: YYMMDDHHMMSS
I have a date_diff that returns the proper values that will be used to update the existing YYMMDDHHMMSS value in SQL, however I don't know if there is a way to make sure each "pair" has 2 characters. If the date_diff returns an hour value of 6, how could I make that 06 without affecting a return of minute 11? I put the 0 in the year and month, as these will always be a value of 0. However the remaining fields may be a return of a single character or 2 characters.

```
$diff->format("0%y years 0%m months %d days, %h hours and %i minutes %s seconds");
```

Would I be forced to check each % return individually or is there another way to format this?

Thanks for any info or thoughts.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is beyond the scope of DateDiff, you should simply use `str_pad` :

- `str_pad('9', 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);` will return `09`
- `str_pad('19', 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);` will return `19`

Comment: Thanks Maxime. Worked like a charm. Much appreciated.